# I cannot find my Bluemix Applications, where are they?

Tags: ibm-cloud

Can anyone help me with Bluemix?

At this moment, Bluemix is down for all of our applications.

I am getting a 404 error on DNS to our application.

I can sign-in on Bluemix but all the applications are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that when you say "all the applications are gone" you mean that you can't find your runtimes both using the UI and the cf CLI (*cf apps* command) I'd suggest you to open a support request using one of the following methods:

- Use the Support Widget. It is available from the user avatar in the 
     upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI.  After opening the support 
     widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch , select the type of 
     assistance you need, and then fill out the support form.
- Use the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget.  Go to http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.

Doing what described above you'll engage the Bluemix DevOps team to deeper investigate the reason why your runtimes seem to be gone. Please remember to provide org, space and application name.

Answer (score 0):

Using the command line use the cf cli and list the apps just so that you know whether it is a problem with the UI. The syntax is:

*cf login -a `End Point` -u `UserId` -p `password` -o `Org` -s `Space`*

where

-a Endpoint=https://api.ng.bluemix.net(US-South) or https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net(London)
-u Bluemix userID
-p Bluemix Password

You can omit -o and -s arguments and you will be prompted to choose from the available orgs and spaces. Once you login successfully, list the apps using the command

*cf apps*

Let me know if the above command returns the list of apps. If it does, please try using a private window (Firefox) or an incognito window (Chrome) and login to Bluemix and see if the UI shows the apps.

Kailash